# Laravel relationship one to many BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::sync()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Aunque he trabajado en Laravel, aún soy muy novato.
He creado tres tablas, clientes, destino y viajes.

Comparto el enlace de mi proyecto de pruebas ([aquí](https://github.com/uldcra/viajes))

Lo que quiero intentar es que hay muchos clientes y muchos destinos, con lo cual creo una tabla intermedia.

Lo que intento es cuando se guarde cliente también guarde todos sus destinos, quería hacerlo con sync, para añadir varios destinos en el momento, pero algo hago mal.
Modelo cliente

```
class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table =  'clients';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'dni','phone'
    ];

    public function destinationsClients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientDestination::class);
    }
}
```

modelo cliente_destino

```
class ClientDestination extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'clients_destination';

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the ClientDestination
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function clients(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}
```

Aunque falta Destination de momento lo tengo vacio, no se si tendría que añadir algo.
Client controller

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Client;

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
   public function storeClient( Request $request) {
       $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
       $client = new Client;
       $client->fill($data);
       $client->save();
       $client->destinationsClients()->sync([1]);
       return response()->json($data, 200);
   }
}
```

cuando guardo solo se guarda el cliente, pero la tabla intermedia no consigo hacer nada.
Me da estos errores
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::sync()

o

TypeError: Return value of App\Models\Client::destinationsClients() must be an instance of App\Models\HasMany,

si añado al modelo

```
 public function destinationsClients(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientDestination::class);
    }
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Estás definiendo las relaciones con One To Many, en vez de [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, voy adjuntar el código por si le sirve alguien.

Comment: Si te parece bien, agrega una explicación de que es lo que cambiaste, además de mostrar el código. Así ya borramos los comentarios y queda todo en la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Modelo Cliente

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table =  'clients';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'dni','phone'
    ];

    public function destinationsClients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ClientDestination::class,'clients_destination','client_id','destination_id');
    }
}
```

y en el controlador

```
public function storeClient( Request $request) {
       $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
       $client = new Client;
       $client->fill($data);
       $client->save();
       $client->destinationsClients()->sync(
           [
               ['client_id'=>20, 'destination_id'=> 1  ],
               ['client_id'=>20, 'destination_id'=> 2  ],
               ['client_id'=>21, 'destination_id'=> 1  ],
            ]
        );
       return response()->json($data, 200);
   }
```